# How is my lambda function getting the match as an argument in my re.subn() expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, lambda

I have a re.sub that searches for and increments a number.  I searched the web for this solution.  The solution works but I don't understand how the lambda function is obtaining its argument.  As far as I know the re.subn() returns a tuple of the result string and the number of changes.  It does not give you access to the matched string but somehow lambda is getting access to it.

```
resultstring, nmatches = re.subn(regex, lambda m: '{}{}'.format(m.group(1), int(m.group(2)) + 1), originalstring)
```

`m` is the string matched by `regex` and m.group(n) the captured groups.

Please inform me what is going on here.

Comment: " It does not give you access to the matched string but somehow lambda is getting access to it." because whoever wrote the `re.subn` wrote it so that it passes the matched string to the callable you pass in.

Comment: Thanks.  What is this technique called so I can learn more about it?

Comment: Probably what you are looking for is "callback" and "higher order functions"